# Show print dialog - print Word document from Excel

Tags: excel, printing, dialog, ms-word, vba

please could someone help me? I use mail merge and Word document as a template for labels. After execution of mail merge I need to show word print dialog for printer selection and to be able set label details in printer properties. I tried to set destination of mail merge to `wdSendToPrinter` , call `dialog` various ways e.g. `wd.Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Display` but nothing works. Do you have any other suggestion, please?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim wdDoc, wd As Object
Dim template, excel As String, merge As String

template = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template\templateA4.docx"
excel = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

On Error Resume Next
 Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wdDoc = wd.documents.Open(template)

wdDoc.Application.Visible = False

 wdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=excel, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Revert:=False, _
        Connection:="Data Source=" & excel & ";Mode=Read", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `List1$`"


With wdDoc.MailMerge
     .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
     .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
     .SuppressBlankLines = True
     With .DataSource
      .FirstRecord = 1
      .LastRecord = 5
     End With
     .Execute Pause:=False
End With

merge = wdDoc.Application.activedocument.Name
wdDoc.Application.documents(template).Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
wdDoc.Application.Visible = True
wd.Application.documents(merge).Activate
```

'need to show word print dialog at this point

```
wdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False

wdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set wdDoc = Nothing
wd.Application.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wd.Dialogs(88).Show` instead of `wd.Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Display`